# Add parameters from a predefined string in a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, paste, assign

I am running a for loop where I a trying to embed a specific subset for each iteration in the code.

```
formu<-c("all$Tonnage>= extr_out_hi","all$Tonnage< extr_out_low")

for (i in 1:5){
Tons<-sum(all$Tonnage[formu],na.rm=T)
m[i]<-Tons
}
```

However, I do not receive any results. How do I adjust the code so R reads the objects in "formu" as directions for subsetting the frame and not as a string?

Comment: `Tons<-sum(all$Tonnage[eval(parse(text=formu)),],na.rm=T)`

Comment: But this will only test `all$Tonnage< extr_out_low` not sure why... not sure what you're expecting though...